# Can someone tell me a Hadith related to positivity in life?

Tags: hadith, reference-request, life

I have to share a hadith in my university class, for that I love to recite Hadith about being positive in life.

Comment: Would you mind being more specific on what you mean by "positivity in life" or giving us some helpful details on what your expectations are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are living a normal life having what keep you a live this is a lot (that does not mean you don't look after your self) because there are people who being born in a country at war from the beginning of his or here life they will suffer and who have disease(ابتلاء) since childhood that can not be cure test from Allah,  a lot other situation so having what other people don't have this is a lot.

> عن عبيد الله بن محصن الأنصاري الخطمي رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ قال رسول
>   الله صلى الله عليه وسلم‏:‏ ‏ "‏ من أصبح منكم آمنا في سربه، معافى في
>   جسده، عنده قوت يومه، فكأنما حيزت له الدنيا بحذافيرها‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه
>   الترمذي وقال‏:‏ حديث حسن‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
>
> Ubaidullah bin Mihsan Al-Ansari (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Whosoever begins the day feeling family security and good health; and possessing provision for his day is as though he possessed the whole world." ([Riyadussaliheen](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/511))
>
> Whoever among you wakes up in the morning secure in his dwelling, healthy in his body, and he has his food for the day, then it is as if the whole world has been given to him ([Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/43))